# Town Network - Show there is a Tetrahedron of the Same Transport

Tags: number-theory

**Question:** There are 18 towns such that between each pair of towns there is either a train or bus service (not both). Prove that there are 4 towns such that all 6 of their pairwise connections use the same mode of transport.

**Attempt:** I have already shown for the case of 6 towns, it is possible to visit 3 towns in a loop without going to any other towns via the same mode of transport (via pigeonhole principle). The question above however wants me to show the existence of a tetrahedron where the lines are of all the same transport.

I don't see any way how I can link the case of 6 towns to 18 towns and the method I used for the case of 6 towns is far too long-winded for 18 towns. Can anyone help me here? Note I am a first year mathematician so I can't be using results in Graph Theory etc.